# Is there a max number of devices that adb can detect

Tags: android, adb

I was wondering if there is a maximum number of devices that android adb tools can detect? I didn't find any answer on Google. I already connected 13 devices successfully but I don't know if it still working for more devices.

Thanks.

Comment: The answer to this is likely to be found by reading the ADB source code, to either literally discover a limit, or discover the number of system resources used (for example, it may be that each consumes a socket, and there may be an OS limit on those).  In practice, I suspect you will find the collection of devices unwieldy long before you hit a hard limit.

Comment: I have 30 devices available today I'll try to connect them. I checked in adb source code if there were a limit but didn't see anything. It seems that the only limit is the number of devices your computer can handle. :)

Comment: It's working for 30 devices.

Comment: We want some photos ;-)

Comment: I'm waiting for some hub to tried to connect 80 tablets ! :D ! If it's working, we would be able to say that there is no limit ! :)

Comment: You can also connect to the devices over tcp-ip on port 5555. So if you share a LAN you could add more devices that way. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is no adb limit but there is an usb controller limit depending of your controller (~10 devices/controller).